How to toggle between different VS Code layouts?
I have several panels open on VS Code (explorer, git history, terminal, etc.). I want to save this view including the sizing of the panels and then create a separate view that has different panels open with different sizing.
Essentially what I'm trying to do is set up a "big monitor view" and a "laptop view" that I can easily toggle between depending on available screen real estate.
Is there an easy way to do this?

Have you tried using the Profiles? As far as I know, they store the state of the UI.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles
